# Como usar injeção de dependência fora de uma Controller com ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, injeção-de-dependência

Tenho seguinte código:

```
public class ContaController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAppServiceUsuario _app;

    public ContaController(IAppServiceUsuario _app)
    {
        this._app = _app;
    }
}
```

como injetar dependência com `Ninject` usando essa mesma `IAppServiceUsuario` em outra classe que não seja uma `Controller`  ?

Esta mapeada assim no `Ninject`:

```
kernel.Bind<IAppServiceUsuario>().To<AppServiceUsuario>();
```

Classe que onde deveria instanciar `IAppServiceUsuario`

```
 public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private IAppServiceUsuario _app;

        public AuthorizationServerProvider(IAppServiceUsuario _app)
        {
            this._app = _app;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Método para validar o token no cache do Oauth
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add("User", "");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Metodo para verificar as credenciais de acesso
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            if (_app.Autenticar(context.UserName, context.Password) != null)
            {
                Claim claim1 = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName);
                Claim[] claims = new Claim[] { claim1 };
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity =
                    new ClaimsIdentity(
                       claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                context.Validated(claimsIdentity);
            }
            else
            {
                context.SetError("Erro na validação", "Usuario ou senha Inválidos");
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eduardo, coloque essa classe e como está instanciando, fazendo favor?

Comment: adicionei a classe

Comment: Eduardo já tentou colocar no Ninject `kernel.Bind<OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<AuthorizationServerProvider >();` para ver se funciona? você só esqueceu de falar como está instânciando isso? ou isso é o App que faz?

Comment: IAppServiceUsuario instancia ha AppServiceUsuario

Comment: Sim Eduardo isso eu entendi, mas, como passou para o construtor de outra classe o Ninject precisa saber para ele injetar nela também por isso eu perguntei **Eduardo já tentou colocar no Ninject kernel.Bind<OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<Authoriza‌​tionServerProvider >();**?

Comment: assim não consegui

Answer (score 2):

Quando vc faz o kernel.Bind().To(), o Ninject já injeta dependência e quando vc chamar a classe ele cria ela para vc.

Exemplo:

```
public class Repository : IRepository {
 ...
}

public class Domain : IDomain {    
  public Domain(IRepository repository){}   
  ...
}
public class AppService : IAppService { 
  public AppService (IDomain domain ){} 
   ...
}

public class SomeControllerController: ApiController{ 
  public SomeControllerController(IAppService appService){} 
  ...
}


kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();
kernel.Bind<IDomain>().To<Domain>();
kernel.Bind<IAppService>().To<AppService>();
```

Comment: sim no controller funciona perfeitamente mas quando tento usar fora da controller ele não consegue injetar iria usar método contido  no repositorio para autenticar usuário em outra classe

Comment: Se você injetar a dependência do que vc precisa na classe que vc precisa ? Ou pode colocar o IKernel como dependência na sua domain por exemplo, e instanciar por ele o que vc precisa,Se você injetar a dependência do que vc precisa na classe que vc precisa ? Ou pode colocar o IKernel como dependência na sua domain por exemplo, e instanciar por ele o que vc precisa; `var teste = kernel.Get<IAlgumaCoisa>();`